# What happens if I use "&" with string in scanf function?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I just saw some code in a blog.
It used

```
scanf("%s",&T);
```

but as we know, we shouldn't use ampersand with a string because it automatically assigns the first address of that string. I did run that code, and surprisingly it is working, so I want to know what happens when I use `&` in string?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char T[2];
    scanf("%s", &T);
    printf("You entered %s\n", T);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &T);` has a bigger problem: no width limit.  Use `scanf("%1s", T);` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant part of the code snippet is:

```
char T[2];
scanf("%s", &T);
```

`&T` is a pointer to the array of two characters (`char (*)[2]`). This is not the type that `scanf` needs for a `%s` specifier: it needs a pointer to a character (`char *`). So the behavior of the program is undefined.

The correct way to write this program, as you know, is

```
char T[2];
scanf("%s", T);
```

Since `T` is an array, when it is used in most contexts, it “decays” to a pointer to the first character: `T` is equivalent to `&(T[0])` which has the type `char *`. This decay does not happen when you take the address of the array (`&T`) or its size (`sizeof(T)`).

In practice, almost all platforms use the same representation for all pointers to the same address. So the compiler generates exactly the same code for `T` and `&T`. There are some rare platforms that may generate different code (I've heard of them but I couldn't name one). Some platforms use different encodings for “byte pointers” and “word pointers”, because their processor natively addresses words, not bytes. On such platforms, an `int *` and a `char *` that point to the same address have different encodings. A cast between those types converts the value, but misuse in something like a variable argument list would result in the wrong address. I would expect such platforms to use byte addresses for a char array, however. There are also rare platforms where a pointer encodes not only the address of the data, but also some type or size information. However, on such platforms, the type and size information would have to be equivalent: it's a block of 2 bytes, starting at the address of `T`, and addressable byte by byte. So this particular mistake is unlikely to have any practical impact.

Note that it would be completely different if you had a pointer instead of an array in the first place:

```
char *T; // known to point to an array of two characters
scanf("%s", &T); // bad
```

Here `&T` is a pointer to the location in memory that contains the address of the character array. So `scanf` would write the characters that it reads at the location where the pointer `T` is stored in memory, not at the location that `T` points to. Most compilers analyze the format string of functions like `printf` and `scanf` and so would emit an error message.

Note that `char T[2]` only has room for two characters, and this includes the null byte at the end of the string. So `scanf("%s", T)` only has room to read a single character. If the input contains more than one non-whitespace character at this point, the program will overflow the buffer. To read a single character and make it a one-character string, use

```
char T[2];
scanf("%c", T);
T[1] = 0;
```

Unlike `scanf("%s", T)`, this reads any character, even whitespace. To read a string with a length limit, add a limit to the `%s` specification. You should never use an unlimited `%s` in `scanf` since this will read as much input as is available, regardless of how much room there is to store this input in memory.

```
char T[2];
scanf("%1s", T); // one less than the array size
```

Answer (score 4):

Technically speaking, this is a type mismatch, leading to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). For scanning a *string*, the expected argument is a pointer to the initial element of a character array.

When you have an array `t` of type `char[somevalue]`, when you say

```
scanf("%s",t);
```

`t` decays to a pointer to the first element, so that is OK.

On the other hand, when you say `&t`, it is of type `char (*)[somevalue]` - pointer to an array, the whole array, not the pointer to the the initial element of the array.

Now, since the address of the array and the address of the first element of the array are *same* (memory location), so, writing the scanned value to the supplied address may not lead to any problem and work as intended - but this is neither defined nor recommended.

Comment: While technically a type mismatch, has there ever been a platform or do you think there will likely ever be a platform where the two pointers could differ? Do any of the C standards ever allow them to differ?

Comment: @MadPhysicist C allows the pointer to a `char*` and a pointer to `char` to differ in size, layout, passing conventions, etc.  Technically it is UB, but rarely a big issue.  Competent compilers will warn.

Comment: @chux. Just to clarify (because I never seem to get this right), the pointer to the array is always going to be equivalent to a `char *` pointer?

Comment: @MadPhysicist They differ in type - and they are not compatible. For example, try pointer arithmetic on both the pointers.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: An artificial platform designed specifically for this sort of stress-testing of C code might deliberately adopt different object representations for these two pointer types. This is allowed by the language specification.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The problem is that `char*` and `char (*)[]` are not compatible pointer types. The optimizing compiler is therefore free to assume weird things such as "the contents of this array are never written to". In theory, something like this is possible: `char str[] = "foo"; scanf("%s", &str); puts(str);`. The user types "bar" but the code prints "foo", since the compiler assumes that `str` is never accessed after initialization and optimizes the code accordingly.

Comment: @MadPhysicist [Re](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332187/what-happens-if-i-use-with-string-in-scanf-function/53332264?noredirect=1#comment93544696_53332264).  Yes "pointer to the array is always going to be equivalent to a char * pointer" is true in value, yet 5.0 == 5 is also true.  Being equivalent values is insufficient.  `"%s"` expects a certain type.  A pointer to an array is not necessarily an equivalent type as `char *`.